# Sharepoint List creation from ListTemplet .stp using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, csom

I want to create list using .stp file which is uploaded in to the list template Gallary.

--> I am using Console application to create list in online site.
--> have an any idea how to add list from stp file at online site.

I am not getting custom list using below code.

```
listTemplate = Context.Web.ListTemplates.First(t => t.ListTemplateTypeKind == TemplateID);
```

Code Gives me OOTB list template .

```
Document Library
Form Library
Wiki Page Library
Picture Library
Links
Announcements
Contacts
Calendar
Discussion Board
Promoted Links
Key Dates
Tasks (2010)
Project Tasks
Tasks
Issue Tracking
Locations
Persons
Custom List
Announcements
Lessons Learnt
Risk Register
Issues Register
Daily Log
Custom List in Datasheet View
External List
Survey
Converted Forms
Draft Apps
Report Library
Asset Library
Status List
Access App
Workflow History
Custom Workflow Process
Maintenance Log Library Template
Pages Library

Data Connection Library
No Code Workflows
Data Sources
Persistent Storage List for MySite Published Feed
No Code Public Workflows
```

How should i get .stp list template in context ?